# Django dynamic nested model forms

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose I have the following models, where there is a 1:many relationship from `Teacher` to `Course`, and from `Course` to `Student`:

```
class Teacher(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
    degree = CharField(max_length=64)

class Course(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=64)
    level = CharField(max_length=64)
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Student(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
    year = CharField(max_length=64)
    course = ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

If I want to have a "register teacher" page, where a user can input the details of a `Teacher`, and also be able to add any number of `Course`s with their corresponding details, and to each `Course` add any number of `Student`s, how could this be done? I am aware of `ModelForm`s, which would make constructing a basic form for a single instance of a model rather trivial, but how can I create a form or forms that essentially nests the models within each other, and allows for a dynamic number of `Course` and `Student`?

For example, within the `Teacher` form, there is an "add Course" button, that adds another `Course` form under that `Teacher`, such that any details entered into it populate a `Course` that belongs to that `Teacher`, and then for each `Course` form, there is an "add Student" button that adds a `Student` form for a `Student` that belongs to that `Course`. How can I implement this dynamic and nested behavior?

Then if it is possible to make such a form, back on the Python side after the form is submitted, how will the data be organized? Or in other words, what will indicate to which `Course` each `Student` belongs?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Django ModelFormsets, it is used in those cases

Comment: Is there any existing functionality to add more instances of a form to the page once the page is loaded? Like an "add course" button?

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: I cannot seems to find an answer on how to, if at all, use model formsets in multi-level nesting, e.g. A is inside B which is inside C which is inside D. I only find what appears to apply for one level of nesting

Comment: Is `inlineformset_factory` or anything similar, applicable if I have a `OneToOneField`? Trying using the same methodology, if `A` has a `OneToOneField(B)`, and a `ForeignKey(Z)`, `inlinefactory_formset(Z, A, ...)` is fine, but calling `inlineformset_factory(A, B, ...)` raises `B has to ForeignKey to A`